Fixing this for SD Ellipse TypeError: setValue(self, value: int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
I am a beginner QGIS attempting to complete a homework assignment however I am running into this issue. I've never used python so I don't know how to fix the error even if I open the code with R.
This is my error:
2024-10-03T22:54:17     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "_________ (removed personal data)
default/python/plugins\SDEllipse\SDEllipse.py", line 127, in run
self.dlg.progressBar.setValue(0.0)
TypeError: setValue(self, value: int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'

Your code is expecting an integer, like 1, 2, 3, or 4.
But you are passing in a float, specifically 0.0.
I would change the line 127 to:
self.dlg.progressBar.setValue(0)

